# How to make documents automatically download to my server after the recipient sign them with Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

Im using docusign connect and I get the info of every envelope completed with my listener, but how can i download the documents with this info?

I read i can use the esignature api to get the documents but I need the documents to be automatically downloaded to my server without login in the browser to get the access token. How can i do that?

I'm working with php sdk

I tried Agreement Actions but only works with predifined apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JWT Authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) to obtain an access token which is a way to authenticate service integrations (which is what you might be looking for). You can use the Connect event as a trigger to make an API call to the eSignature REST API to fetch the envelope documents.

Answer (score 0):

Karan gave you a good answer and that's a good option.

Another option is to include the document in the payload, it will be base64 encoded, so there's a performance hit and it will be slower, but you won't need to make a separate API call in that case.

[DocuSign Custom Connect - How to make a listener in php example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309848/docusign-custom-connect-how-to-make-a-listener-in-php-example) has some discussion of this and PHP code as well.